# The brightness of direct sunlight that passes through a sheet of glass is reduced by 10% Determine an expression

Tags: calculus

The brightness of direct sunlight that passes through a sheet of glass is reduced by 10% Determine an expression for the precent of the original brightness of sunlight left after it passes through 6 sheets of glass

my attempt:

Each passage reduces the light intensity by 10% so that the remaining intensity after passing through the glass is 90% of the intensity prior to passage.

After 6 passages, the remaining intensity will be (.90)^6 = 0.531441 or about 53.1% of the original intensity.

Comment: Is there any part you are uncertain about?

Comment: ya I think im wrong ? am i ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it depends on who is asking the question!!!

If this is a simple exercise on percentages from some math book then you have have the right idea. Since the remaining 10% is assumed to simply vanish.

If, however, the question is from an electrodynamics or other physics book, the answer is more complex.

Let me give you the gist of the answer, since it is easy to get confused and make an error. for simplicity I will only take two sheets.

```
    |   .9|
--> |  -->| --> .9*.9
    |     |
```

This is the naive approach assuming  the remaining 10% goes away. A physics text would point out that the remaining  light is reflected.

So we have a bit more ( physicists call it corrections )

```
    |.1*.9|
<-- | <-- |  
    |     |
```

.1*.9 is reflected back.

Hits the first sheet then gets reflected back. to the second sheet.

```
    | .1*.1*.9|
    |      -->| --> .9*.9*.1*.1 
    |         |
```

But now a bit more is reflected back at the first sheet. Actually .1*.1*.1*.9. So you have an infinite series of corrections you have to lay out.

Hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the initial amount of direct sunlight is 10.

Using the formula $a(1-r)^n$ where $a$ is the direct sunlight, r is the rate of reduction and n is the number of passes through the glass:

Note that: 10% = $.1$

$10(1-.1)^6$ = $5.31441$

Now:
$\frac {5.31441}{10} * 100 = 53.1441$

We have 53.1441% of the initial intensity.